# Getting a file from a branch into GIT

Tags: git

So I updated all of my repositories from origin with git fetch, and this downloaded several files from my non-master branch (let's call it "test", for argument). However it did not update a particular file that I wanted to update to that branch - let's call it "file.name".

File.name already existed locally, but I want to overwrite it with this branch - how would I go about doing that? I have changes that I want to checkout and see if they work.

Answer (score 1):

`git cat-file` is one way to do it:

```
git cat-file -p master:dir/dir/dir/file.txt > file.txt
```

Comment: I don't want to overwrite the actual master branch with this, just the local file, I want to clarify.

Comment: The command above extracts the dir/dir/dir/file.txt file from master branch and writes it to file.txt.

Comment: This answer does exactly what you want because it doesn't add the file to the index.  It just changes the working copy.  That's why it's superior (for you) to the general answer of ``git checkout master -- dir/dir/dir/file.txt``